# PyInstaller Command not Found on Mac

Tags: path, pip, pyinstaller

I used pip to install pyinstaller on my mac. When using the pyinstaller command it says "-bash: pyinstaller: command not found". I know that I need to add its path to my bash profile, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: `pip show -f pyinstaller | grep Location | sed 's/^Location: //' | xargs -I {} readlink -f {}/../../../bin` should be the path. Check if `/ful/printed/path/to/bin/pyinstaller --help` works, then open `~/.bash_profile` and add lines `PATH="/full/printed/path/to/bin:${PATH}"` and `export PATH`, save. Now run `source ~/.bash_profile` or reopen the terminal.

Comment: Are you using an anaconda python distribution? If so, you may need to install pyinstaller using `conda install pyinstaller` from the anaconda prompt instead